# Inserting different tables using same database file in sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database file which have insert method, update method, select method for one particular table and particular data.
But I have two different tables with different types of data. 
What is the best way to use that file for using different tables and data?

```
package com.fahimchowdhury.myapplication;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
    Created by Misbah Ahmad Chowdhury Fahim on 8/27/2016.
 */

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String DB_NAME = "EXAMDB";

    //private static final String ID_COLUMN = "id";
    private static final String NAME_COLUMN = "name";
    private static final String EMAIL_COLUMN = "email";
    private static final String PASS_COLUMN = "password";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "examTable";
    //private static final String DB_VERSION = "dbVersion";

    private static final String COMMA = ",";
    private  static final String PRIMARY_KEY = " PRIMARY KEY";
    //private  static final String AUTO_INCREMENT = " AUTOINCREMENT";
    //private  static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
    //private  static final String INTEGER_TYPE = " INTEGER";
    private  static final String VARCHAR_TYPE = " VARCHAR";


    private static final String TABLE_CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ TABLE_NAME + "(" +
            NAME_COLUMN + VARCHAR_TYPE + COMMA +
            EMAIL_COLUMN + VARCHAR_TYPE + PRIMARY_KEY + COMMA +
            PASS_COLUMN + VARCHAR_TYPE + ")";


    private static final String SELECT_ALL_QUERY = "Select *  From " + TABLE_NAME;



    private  Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory cursorFactory;


    //Constructor, Database can be created/opened by calling this constructor

    public DBHelper(Context context, int version){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, version);
        this.context = context;
    }
    public DBHelper(Context context, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory cursorFactory, int version){
        super(context, DB_NAME, cursorFactory, version);
        this.context = context;
        this.cursorFactory = cursorFactory;
    }


    @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase dBase) {
        try {
            //Log.d("Creating_DB_from", "OnCreate");
            dBase.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE_QUERY);
        } catch (Exception e){
            //Log.d("Creating Exception ", "Creating Exception : "+e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long insertRow(Info info){
        SQLiteDatabase dBase;

        try {

            dBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues  values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(NAME_COLUMN, info.getName());
            values.put(EMAIL_COLUMN, info.getEmail());
            values.put(PASS_COLUMN, info.getPassword());

            dBase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            dBase.close();
            return  1;

        } catch (SQLiteException ex){

            //e.printStackTrace(); //comment printstack before releasing
        }
        return  -1;
    }


    //selecting all rows from database and returning an arraylist of a class type
    public ArrayList<Info> getAllRows(){
        SQLiteDatabase dBase;
        try{
            dBase = this.getReadableDatabase();
            ArrayList<Info> profiles = new ArrayList<>();
            Info info = new Info();
            Cursor cursor = dBase.rawQuery(SELECT_ALL_QUERY, null);

            if (cursor.getCount()<=0)
                return  null;

            DataContainer indices = new DataContainer(cursor);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                //Setting All property of info object then add to the arraylist
                info.setName(cursor.getString(indices.nameColumnIndex));
                info.setEmail(cursor.getString(indices.emailColumnIndex));
                info.setPassword(cursor.getString(indices.passColumnIndex));
                profiles.add(info);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());

            cursor.close();
            dBase.close();
            return profiles;

        } catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace(); //comment print stack before releasing
        }
        return  null;
    }

    //Authorize an user to log in
    public int authorizeUser(String email, String userPass){
        SQLiteDatabase dBase;

        try{
            dBase = this.getReadableDatabase();
            String[] arg = {email, userPass};
            // 1st question mark will be replaced with email and 2nd one with userPass, last parameter "1" is the limit
            Cursor cursor = dBase.query(true, TABLE_NAME, null, EMAIL_COLUMN+"=? AND "+ PASS_COLUMN + "=?",
                    arg, null, null, null, "1");
            if(cursor.getCount()>0){
                //email password matched

                cursor.close();
                dBase.close();

                return 1;
            } else {
                cursor.close();
                dBase.close();

                return 0;
            }

        } catch (SQLiteException e){
            e.printStackTrace(); //comment print stack before releasing
        }
        return  -1;
    }


    public Info getAuthorizedUser(String email, String userPass){
        String[] arg = {email, userPass};

            SQLiteDatabase dBase;
            try {
                dBase = this.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor = dBase.query(true, TABLE_NAME, null, EMAIL_COLUMN+ "=? AND "+ PASS_COLUMN+"=?", arg, null, null, null, "1");
                if(cursor.getCount()>0){
                    //user is found, extract all info(s) from cursor
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    DataContainer indices = new DataContainer(cursor);

                    //Make an object of fetched data to return
                    Info info = new Info(
                            cursor.getString(indices.nameColumnIndex),
                            cursor.getString(indices.emailColumnIndex),
                            cursor.getString(indices.passColumnIndex));
                    cursor.close();
                    dBase.close();
                    return info;
                }
            } catch (SQLException e){
                //e.printStackTrace(); //comment print stack before releasing

            }

        return null;
    }
    public Info getAuthorizedUser(String email){
        String[] arg = {email};

            SQLiteDatabase dBase;
            try {
                dBase = this.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor = dBase.query(true, TABLE_NAME, null, EMAIL_COLUMN+ "=?", arg, null, null, null, "1");
                if(cursor.getCount()>0){
                    //user is found, extract all info(s) from cursor
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    DataContainer indices = new DataContainer(cursor);

                    //Make an object of fetched data to return
                    Info info = new Info(
                            cursor.getString(indices.nameColumnIndex),
                            cursor.getString(indices.emailColumnIndex),
                            cursor.getString(indices.passColumnIndex));
                    cursor.close();
                    dBase.close();
                    return info;
                }
            } catch (SQLException e){
                //e.printStackTrace(); //comment print stack before releasing

            }

        return null;
    }



    private class DataContainer{

        int nameColumnIndex;
        int emailColumnIndex;
        int passColumnIndex;
        DataContainer(Cursor cursor){
            this.nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(NAME_COLUMN);
            this.emailColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(EMAIL_COLUMN);
            this.passColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PASS_COLUMN);
        }

        public int getIndex(Cursor cursor, String columnName){
            return cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put new method like insert

```
      insert_tableName1()
```

and

```
    insert_tableName2()
```

if you have the different types of data and different argument count. if you have to the same number of arguments means and same type of data means you can use same method like following

```
       insert_table(String tableName, Info info){
       dBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues  values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(NAME_COLUMN, info.getName());
        values.put(EMAIL_COLUMN, info.getEmail());
        values.put(PASS_COLUMN, info.getPassword());

        dBase.insert(tableName, null, values);
        dBase.close();
        }
```

Comment: what if I create different classes for different data types  extending this DBHelper class?
or, if I overload every methods for every types of data?

Comment: with overloading you can do that for that you have to define more methods..